# send email to constant email address

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an app that need to send e-mail to constant e-mail address.
i used this code to send e-mail until now:

```
NSString *subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Login Info",self.name];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username : %@ \n Password : %@ \n E-Mail : %@ \n Sequrity Question : %@ \n Sequrity Answer : %@" ,self.user,self.password,self.email,self.seqQuestion,self.seqAnswer];
    NSLog(@"%@",body);
    NSString *mailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@",
                            [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                            [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
                            [body stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mailString]];
```

The problem came with this is when the user that used the app not defined an e-mail address in is iphone' mail app so he can't send the mail.

there is any other way for sendding e-mail to constant e-mail address?

Comment: i looked for this class and didn't found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a mailto: url link, why not use the SDK's email/messaging system?

Check if the user can send an email first

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
```

If this returns NO, the user can't send email.  Perhaps show a message suggesting they might want to configure the email settings.

If they can send a message (ie email is configured), then compose and send the email

```
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"Subject goes here"];
    NSString *msgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message body"];
    [controller setMessageBody:msgString isHTML:NO]; 
    [viewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

If you find the user can't send an email in the first instance, you will either have to write your own service and connect to that (via a webservice, perhaps) or you will have to write your own implementation of the email protocol to connect to a known server with a known account.

Comment: the problem with this class is if the user not defined an e-mail address in is iphone' mail app so he can't send the mail

Comment: But if you use a mailto: URL, then it will use the iphone's mail app anyway.  At least this way you are getting to know if the user has it defined and either don't send it, or alert the user.  mailto: will just use the email app in the same way http: will just use the web app (Mobile safari).

Comment: and there is any way to do it with http request?

Comment: If you want to do it with an http request, then you will have to have your own webservice running on the webhost.  This could be done in any number of ways - I would suggest a simple php page that writes to a text file would be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a mail directly you can set up a simple web service that sends the mail for you; that way you don't need to rely on any correct setup on the phone, apart of course from a working internet connection.

Comment: @yosifz8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968107/http-post-request This question should be informative.