# how to send user name and password using post to server in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am making a lo-gin app i want to send the username and password to server for validation how to do this i have done in many ways but i am unable to post.
I am posting the username and password but it did not work if i direct give username and password to php it works so how to do this in iphone to send through post

```
NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",username,pass];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/connect.php?"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];      

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Inside the else condition");
}

[nameInput resignFirstResponder];
[passInput resignFirstResponder];
nameInput.text = nil;
passInput.text = nil;
```

Comment: Have a look at [this S.O article][1] that explains how to make a POST request.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968107/http-post-request

Comment: i have looked at this same result

Comment: Add Following Code After

Comment: Just wondering if you are  encrypting the password and then sending it or just sending the plain password..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Edited your code try this may help you.

```
 NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",username,pass];

 NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];  

 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];  

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/connect.php?"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
 [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
 [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: same it does not give any reposne same @""

Comment: Try changing the encoding :                                        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

Comment: Login response:is  SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='' AND  UserPassword=''NO  again same reponse in log

Comment: Now I guess something wrong with your web service of login authentication, as it gives the response but may be query returned from there. As we have done the exact way the "POST" works.

Comment: can u help if you have any webservice simple like that for checking username and password

Comment: Same over here...an empty response from server.

Answer (score 2):

```
//when the user clicks login<action>    


     - (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender {
        NSInteger success = 0;
        @try {
            //to check if username and password feild are filled
            if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

                [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Username and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

            } else {
                NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
                NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
                //post it to your url where your php file is saved for login
                NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz.rohandevelopment.com/new.php"];

                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:url];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
                [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];

                //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
                NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

                if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
                {
                    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                              JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                              error:&error];

                    success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    } else {

                        NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                        [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                    }

                } else {
                    //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    [self alertStatus:@"Please Check Your Connection" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException * e) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
            [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
        }
        if (success) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
                }

    }






    - (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:msg
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        alertView.tag = tag;
        [alertView show];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Following Code After

```
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *response;// = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];

NSError *error;// = [[NSError alloc] init;

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Login response: is %@",str);
```